# Django _get_pk_val() returns None while pk exists

Tags: python, django, mongodb, primary-key

I use Python, Django, djongo and MongoDB. I've created a simple model and want to save and delete documents from my webpage. I manage to save them (checked in DB) with _id being ObjectID type. But when I try to delete them I have AssertionError (object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None). For document `d` I've printed pk by `d.pk` and got a correct value, but when I run `d._get_pk_val()` output is None. Do you know how to let Django know the primary key?

I've tried to assign pk in the model by `_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` but then _id is still of an ObjectID type, but delete() expect it to be int() and fail with an error (int() argument must be a string or a number, not ObjectID).

My model:

```
class DevList(models.Model):
    dev_num = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
    dev_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    dev_descr = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    dev_type = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

And my views use simple `d.save()` `and d.delete()` functions.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you using to save Django models in MongoDB?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I use djongo [ https://github.com/nesdis/djongo ]  It's a driver for Django which allows MongoDB usage. In documentations it said that all Django components are fully supported